# Regex - Keep all digits with length of 10-13 digits

Tags: regex, notepad++

search for regex where Keep all digits with length of 10-13 digits and delete the rest in notepad++

my regex doesnt work
[^\d{10,13}]

it finds numbers with commas too :(

Comment: You want to remove all numbers that have a digit length outside the range of 10-13?

Comment: Two expressions will be easier, one: `\b\d{1,9}\b` and the other one `\b\d{14,}\b` <- these can be deleted.

Comment: The issue is that it finds numbers with commas or you want it to _not_ find numbers with commas?

Comment: do you have 1 number per line? can numbers contain commas?

Comment: Remove all and keep only numbers with length of 10-13
Each line can contain a 10-13 long number and other content like text or short numbers

Comment: (i) Lines with no 10 to 13 digits long number should be deleted altogether? (ii) There are no numbers longer than 13 digits in your input?

Comment: (iii) Will numbers always be surrounded by white space?

Comment: yes thats correct, but a line can caontain the number that im searching for and text

Comment: @xDk you mentioned commas - can numbers contain commas? If so, will they always group 3 digits, eg `1,234,567`?

Comment: the numbers that im searching for contain "no" commas, but other numbers like price can contain commas

Comment: A couple of examples would simplify our task to help you. Can you match all the digit chunks you want with `\b[0-9]{10,13}\b`? Once you know what pattern works for you the rest is easy.

Comment: Ok, no details - the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for

```
^(?:.*?(\d{10,13}).*|.*)$
```

and replacing with

```
\1
```

you keep just the 10 to 13 digit long numbers (and empty lines).

Remove the empty lines searching for

```
^\n
```

and replacing with nothing.

See it in action: [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/jP0gW3/1).

Addressing @WiktorStribiżew's comments: Relying on the sought after numbers to be always surrounded by white space (which has been checked with OP - but not for the potential case, lines to (effectively) hold just numbers) the search expression could be adjusted to

```
^(?:.*\s(\d{10,13})\s.*|.*)$
```

still replacing with

```
\1
```

to handle comma holding strings of numbers correctly: [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/jP0gW3/2)

By the way:

```
[^\d{10,13}]
```

is a character class, which matches anything, which is **not**:

- a number, or
- any character out of "{10,3}" (without the quotes, but including the curly braces).

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: This approach assumes there is only *one single* 10-13 digit chunk on a line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: This is how I understand OP's above comment "[...] Each line can contain a 10-13 long number and other content like text or short numbers"

Comment: Then how do you interpret *it finds numbers with commas too*? Yours will find a `12345678901` in `12,12345678901`. And you do not need a regex to remove empty lines, there is a menu item for that. You might want to use `\R` to match any newline sequence, rather than using `\n` in `^\n`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You are right - though I understand it (primarily) to be a critique on OP's own attempt. - But it might, nevertheless, need to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

To match numbers that are *not* exactly 3 digits long:

```
\b(\d{1,9}|\d{14,})\b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all 10-13 length stand alone digits like this

`(?<!\d)\d{10,13}(?!\d)`

What you do then is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know how does notepad works, but this I think this is the regex you are looking for: ^([0-9]){10,13}$

A good page to create/test regex: http://regexr.com/